# how to set browser settings permanently for Cypress

Tags: cypress

When I run a headed Cypress test in Chrome, I'm tired of needing to change the position of the dev tools (from the right side of the screen to the bottom).

And I also want permanently check the "Preserve log" boxes for both the Network and Console tabs so that logs persist across requests.

How can I permanently set those settings?